# .NET WebAPI - automatic pdf generation

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web, asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation

I have developed an ExtJS 5 + .NET MVC WebAPI RIA for reporting purposes.
Now the client is requesting a feature to subscribe to some reports. The reports (pdf) should be generated automatically and then the server should send them per mail to the user who subscribed a report. It would also be a nice to have that the user can specify the date and time when he will receive the report.

Currently the application has already a PDF export where the user can save these reports. In this case the applications sends the html of the report section to the server and the server is working with [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to generate the pdf.

For my new feature i have the following questions:

1. Can i implement this new feature service in my WebAPI (e.g. as a thread which ill start on startup) or should i write an independet service for it.
2. Would it be appropriate to just load the site on the server with the reports and execute the process which i am already running for my PDF export to get the pdf out of it?

I am thankful for every advice.

Comment: reason for downvote would be nice plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate process that calls the WebApi makes a lot of sense. Separation of concerns and all that. But whether you include it in the API itself or in a separate mailer portal, I suggest you don't try to write any scheduling yourself. Scott Hanselman has [a great post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) on why you shouldn't and suggests several alternatives. Of those, my favorite solution is [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). I use it in production, and it's pretty easy to set up and use.

And if you need nicely formatted emails, I suggest checking out [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) for their composition.

Comment: thank you for your reply - ill read into that asap. though if i click on your postal link i get to the hanselman blog post of your first link